# Shared fetcher in SWRConfig handling different methods

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, swr

i have a SWRConfig with a fetcher.
i made some hooks:

```
function useData() {
  const { data, mutate, error } = useRequest('data');
  return {

    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
    mutate,
  };
}
```

the useRequest is something like this:

```
export const useRequest = (path: string) => {
  if (!path) {
    throw new Error('Path is required');
  }

  const url = `${apiRoute}/api/${path}`;

  const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR(url);

  return { data, mutate, error };
};
```

So in my page i import my hook to fetch data and to mutate as well.

```
  const { mutate, data } = usePayments();
```

is there any way to handle GET and POST using the same fetcher added in the config?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many parameters as you require to the fetcher function.

This is explained in the docs under [Arguments -> Multiple Arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments).

You could use this to pass a request type to the fetcher and determine if you need a post or get (or any other verb).

```
enum RequestType {
    GET,
    POST
}

const fetcher = (url: string, type: RequestType) => {
    console.log(url)
    console.log(type)

    switch (type) {
        case RequestType.GET:
            // Do a get;
            break;
        case RequestType.POST:
            // Do a post
            break;
    }
}

export const useRequest = (path: string, type: RequestType = RequestType.GET) => {
    if (!path) {
      throw new Error('Path is required');
    }
  
    const url = `${apiRoute}/api/${path}`;
  
    // First parameter is used to uniquely identify the request being made.
    // This could just be a string, but it can also be an array of parameters
    // that are needed to make the request (note that if any of the values 
    // in the array fail a reference comparison the request will be triggered again).
    // The values in the array will be provided to the fetcher function as parameters
    // in the same order as they appear in the array (in this case URL followed by type).
    // The second parameter is just assigning a non-default fetcher for this request,
    // this is not needed if you have a single global fetcher that can meet your needs.
    const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR([url, type], fetcher);
  
    return { data, mutate, error };
};
```

Comment: i did:
export const fetcher = async (url: string, options?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> 
but when i use the mutate coming from the hook it doesn't let me pass the fetcher with the params, just the name, so i cannot specify the method apparently.
My aim is to have a single fetcher in the SWRConfig, that should handle all type of requests and to use the Bound mutate coming from the hook so i dont have to add the path again